# Can't Select Another Radio Button When One Is Selected

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button, label

I'm using radio buttons to hack CSS-only tabs, but recently I've had a problem where when one radio button is selected, none of the others can be. When I hover over the label, it doesn't even change background color, like I specified in CSS.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<style>
.content-wrap{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: calc(100% - 80px);
overflow-y: auto;
}
#main-wrap label{
display: block;
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
}
#main-wrap input[type=radio]{

}
#main-wrap [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
background-color: #404040;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #content-history,
#tab2:checked ~ #content-outline,
#tab3:checked ~ #content-edit,
#tab4:checked ~ #content-revise {
display: block;
}
</style>
<div id='main-wrap'>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab1' value=''><label for='tab1' class='metro-icon'>
            <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Time_And_Date/hourglass-64.png" title="Hourglass" width="24">
            </label>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab2' value=''>
            <label for='tab2' class='metro-icon'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Programming/outline-64.png" title="Outline" width="24">
            </label>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab3' value=''>
            <label for='tab3' class='metro-icon'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Editing/pencil_tip-64.png" title="Pencil Tip" width="24">
            </label>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab4' value=''>
            <label for='tab4' class='metro-icon'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Files/edit_file-64.png" title="Edit File" width="24">
            </label>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-history'>
                <div class='main'>
                <p>This is the history tab!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-outline'>
                <div class='main'>
                <p>This is the outline tab!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-edit'>
                <div class='main'>
                <div contenteditable id='main-input'>This is the edit tab!</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-revise'>
                <div class='main'>
                <p>This is the revise tab!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css:

```
#main-wrap input[type=radio]{
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! I didn't think it was a depth problem, can you tell me why/what caused it?

Comment: @wwsalmon I recommend you to use debugger tools of the browsers. There you can see that in your example the `.content-wrap` is above the rest of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `.content-wrap` is above the rest of radio buttons so you cannot press them.

Just remove `height: calc(100% - 80px);` and you will be able to mark the rest of radio buttons.

Also, change the `left` property because if not you are displaying the text above the second radio button so it will never be checked.

```css
.content-wrap{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
left: 100px;
width: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
}
#main-wrap label{
display: block;
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
}
#main-wrap input[type=radio]{

}
#main-wrap [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
background-color: #404040;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #content-history,
#tab2:checked ~ #content-outline,
#tab3:checked ~ #content-edit,
#tab4:checked ~ #content-revise {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='main-wrap'>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab1' value=''><label for='tab1' class='metro-icon'>
            <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Time_And_Date/hourglass-64.png" title="Hourglass" width="24">
            </label>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab2' value=''>
            <label for='tab2' class='metro-icon'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Programming/outline-64.png" title="Outline" width="24">
            </label>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab3' value=''>
            <label for='tab3' class='metro-icon'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Editing/pencil_tip-64.png" title="Pencil Tip" width="24">
            </label>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab4' value=''>
            <label for='tab4' class='metro-icon'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Files/edit_file-64.png" title="Edit File" width="24">
            </label>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-history'>
                <div class='main'>
                <p>This is the history tab!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-outline'>
                <div class='main'>
                <p>This is the outline tab!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-edit'>
                <div class='main'>
                <div contenteditable id='main-input'>This is the edit tab!</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-revise'>
                <div class='main'>
                <p>This is the revise tab!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I ended up just specifying a higher z-index for the radio buttons instead, as suggested by another answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @wwsalmon Just a tip: be aware if you are going to use more than one `z-index` property. In some cases it produces weirds effects.

Answer (score 0):

please remove `display: block` from this style

```
#tab1:checked  #content-history,
#tab2:checked ~ #content-outline,
#tab3:checked ~ #content-edit,
#tab4:checked ~ #content-revise {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
.content-wrap{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;

overflow-y: auto;
}
#main-wrap label{
display: block;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}
#main-wrap input[type=radio]{

}
#main-wrap [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
background-color: #404040;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #content-history,
#tab2:checked ~ #content-outline,
#tab3:checked ~ #content-edit,
#tab4:checked ~ #content-revise {
display: block;
}
</style>
<div id='main-wrap'>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab1' value=''><label for='tab1' class='metro-icon'>
            <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Time_And_Date/hourglass-64.png" title="Hourglass" width="24">
            </label>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab2' value=''>
            <label for='tab2' class='metro-icon'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Programming/outline-64.png" title="Outline" width="24">
            </label>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab3' value=''>
            <label for='tab3' class='metro-icon'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Editing/pencil_tip-64.png" title="Pencil Tip" width="24">
            </label>

            <input type='radio' name='main-wrap' id='tab4' value=''>
            <label for='tab4' class='metro-icon'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/64/Files/edit_file-64.png" title="Edit File" width="24">
            </label>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-history'>
                <div class='main'>
                <p>This is the history tab!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-outline'>
                <div class='main'>
                <p>This is the outline tab!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-edit'>
                <div class='main'>
                <div contenteditable id='main-input'>This is the edit tab!</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='content-wrap' id='content-revise'>
                <div class='main'>
                <p>This is the revise tab!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Check this